# Why do they put cyrillic letters in phishing email?

Tags: phishing

I have just received this email:

```
Fог уоuг ргоtесtіоn, уоuг Αррlе ID іѕ аutоmаtісаllу disabled. 

Wе hаνе ргеνеntеd аn unuѕuаl ѕіgn іn аttеmрt оn уоuг Αррlе ассоunt.Тhіѕ ассоunt hаѕ Ьееn lоскеd Ьесаuѕе ѕіgnіng іn fгоm а nеw lосаtіоn ог fгоm а dіffегеnt dеνісе. Рlеаѕе геνіеw thе ѕіgn іn dеtаіlѕ Ьеlоw: 

Υоuг ассоunt ассеѕѕ hаѕ Ьееn lоскеd fог thе fоllоwіng геаѕоn(ѕ):
Wе сhеск уоuг ассоunt lоgіn wіth оthег dеνісе.
Υоuг ассоunt hаѕ Ьееn lоскеd untіl thіѕ іѕѕuеd hаѕ Ьееn геѕоlνеd, wе wіll wаіtіng fог 1 wеек ог уоuг ассоunt hаѕ Ьееn lоскеd регmаnеntlу.
Whаt tо dо Νехt: 
Рlеаѕе Сlіск thе lоgіn Ьuttоn Ьеlоw tо уоuг Αррlе ассоunt аnd ргоνіdе thе геquеѕtеd іnfогmаtіоn Ьеfоге 1 wеек. Тhгоugh thе ассоunt геνіеw, іf wе dоn't гесеіνеd thе іnfогmаtіоn Ьеfоге thіѕ dеаdlіnе, уоuг ассоunt ассеѕѕ wіll Ье lоскеd регmаnеntlу.
```

Why are these letters used: Ь, ν, к? It makes easier to detect that the message is not genuine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is probably for avoiding automatic spam detection, which is often based on the existence of keywords like `locked`. And `locked` won't match `lоскеd` so the spam filter lets the mail go through, and inattentive users might get tricked.

They also use the cyrillic letters in URLs because they often are non-already taken domains (free to be bought by the spammer) and they look-like the legitimate URL to users, so they often end up leaving their credentials of `lucky.com` to the phising website `luскy.com`